# product between symmetric matrix and transpose matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, transpose

Suppose that B is a symmetric matrix and A generic matrix with $A^T$ its transpose, is it true that:

$B*A = B*A^T $ ?

i think that $B*A = (B^T)*(A^T) = B*(A^T) $ so is true

And if A,B were 2 tensors?

Comment: Why would $BA=B^TA^T$ ??

Comment: If $A,B$ are tensors, what meaning do you give to $BA$ and $A^T$ ???

Answer (score 2):

No it is false because $B=I $ is a symmetric matrix but for all non-symmetric matrix $A$ you have that

$A=I*A\neq I* A^t$

Comment: and if A,B were 2 tensors?

Comment: What means tensor for you?